# com.couchbase.client.java.error.MixedAuthenticationException with Couchbase and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

I am getting an error when executing a code in Spring Boot using Couchbase 6.0 but the same code was running successfully on Couchbase 4.6.2.

```
"Exception in thread "main" com.couchbase.client.java.error.MixedAuthenticationException: Mixed mode authentication not allowed, use Bucket credentials, User credentials (rbac) or Certificate auth"
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseAsyncCluster.java:394)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:350)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:333)
at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster.openBucket(CouchbaseCluster.java:322)
at com.rms.RmsCodeApplication.jsonmethod(RmsCodeApplication.java:37)
at com.rms.RmsCodeApplication.main(RmsCodeApplication.java:30)
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but you need to show your code or no-one will be able to help you.

Comment: Please, consider adding more details in your next questions

Answer (score 2):

Buckets aren't open by default in 6.0. They are secured. You need to create a user with permissions to access the bucket you are trying to use. This is in the admin console. Then supply the username and password to the SDK you are using. I'm not sure off-hand how this is done in the Java SDK. Check the docs.

If you're not sure how to create the user or what permissions to give them, start with the administrator name and password, and work up from there.

To learn more about security in 6.0, start here:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/security/security-overview.html